# Resolving iphone 7 photo pixel data in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

I just imported an image taken from my iphone 7 onto matlab. It turns out that the image has 3d size instead of 2d.

```
boxImage1 = imread('IMG_5175.jpg');

boxImage1      480x640x3            921600  uint8
```

Can anyone explain why the size of image is in 3d instead of just two. I am trying to run object detection tools on a set of images to extract relevant objects.
Thanks,

Comment: Because it's color. It's an RGB image.

Comment: oh I see, is there a way I can convert it into 2 dimensions ?

Comment: Yes there is. I can think of about a half dozen off hand. I can't tell you which one will be the one you need without knowing a lot more about what you're doing to the image after it's converted. But what I think you really need is a basic text or good tutorial on image processing.

Comment: any recommendation for the book or tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the three dimensions corresponds with the R, G and B channels. Have a look into the [matlab documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#output_argument_d0e480210):

> - If the file contains a truecolor image, then A is an m-by-n-by-3 array.

Converting it to grayscale, using [rgb2gray](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html), is often a good idea, but it may depend on your application:

```
I = rgb2gray(boxImage1); % 480x640 matrix
```